# How do I get this to do a number of iterations until it meets a certain criterion?

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration, octave

I have written a script for cramer's rule which I require to do a number of iterations until it has met a set criterion? The issue I am dealing with is that I require it to use an initial assumption and then once retrieving an answer to use that answer again in the matrix and repeat that method until it has met whatever criterion I set forth an display the amount of iterations done. I am relatively new to octave or programming in general. I've looked at various text books but nothing seems to give me a clear example of how I would go about this

So the code below is what I've written and it works as I'd like it to however it does not automatically do another iteration because I do not know how to put that into octave instead I have opted to copy this same code multiple times making minor changes to it and I believe there is a simpler way to do this?

```
z=[A*(Q1.^0.852) B*(Q2.^0.852) C*(Q3.^0.852); 1 -1 0; 0 1 -1];
p=[0;4.32;3.28];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
D=z
b=p;
N=length(b);
Di=zeros(N,1);
d=det(D);
D_original = D;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
if (d ~=0)

  for i=1:N;
    D(:,i)=b;
    Di(i)=det(D)/d;
    D=D_original;
  endfor
printf("Iteration No: 1_____________________________________________________\n");

printf("solution is:\n");
Q1x=Di(1,1)
Q2x=Di(2,1)
Q3x=Di(3,1)
printf("____________________________________________________________________\n");
printf("criterion check(percentage):\n");
Q1e1=abs(((abs(Q1x)-abs(Q1))/abs((Q1x))))*100 
Q2e2=abs(((abs(Q2x)-abs(Q2))/abs((Q2x))))*100 
Q3e3=abs(((abs(Q3x)-abs(Q3))/abs((Q3x))))*100 
printf("____________________________________________________________________\n");
else
print("Cramer's Rule not aplicable \n");

endif
```

Comment: You do not store new variables inside the script ( `z.p,D,b...`). Which output values do you copy and use when you perform your second iteration? And where do you insert them before you run the script again? What is `A,B,C` and `Q1,Q2,Q3`? What's the purpose of `b=p`. You typically do stuff like that in order to not keep the values in `p` and not overwrite them, but you don't update the values for either `b` or `p` in the script.

Comment: Hi Stewie all those values are pulled from another script. the values of the output are:
   Q1x=Di(1,1)
   Q2x=Di(2,1)
   Q3x=Di(3,1)

b=p is just there to have meaning in terms of N=length(b) as p is my matrix constants. they are not meant to be overwritten at all I feel like I am writing in tongues to you is how can I add the whole file for you to see what I am trying to do?

Comment: If `Q1x, Q2x, Q3x` are your outputs. Where do you use them as input in the next iteration? In the other script? Unfortunately I don't have the time to look through more than I already have. I'm just trying to help you get help. Someone else might have time, but have a look at the before you post a lot more code. Post a [mcve].

Comment: `Q1x, Q2x, Q3x` are meant to be put in back in `z=[A*(Q1.^0.852) B*(Q2.^0.852) C*(Q3.^0.852); 1 -1 0; 0 1 -1];` which i've written a in a new line. Thank you once again for your help I think what I will do is attempt what that hyperlink has said to do and repost the question in a more logical way. Once again thank you

Comment: In any case, it sounds like you should look up the usage of a `while` loop. It will repeat a block of code until a condition is met.